# MongoDB query with conditional group by statement

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to export  customer records from database of mongoDB. Exported customer records should not have duplicated values. "firstName+lastName+code" is the key to DE-duped the record and If there are two records present in database with same key then I need to give preference to source field with value other than email.

customer (`id,firstName,lastName,code,source`) collection is this.

If there are record 3 records with same unique key and 3 different sources then i need to choose only one record between 2 sources(TV,internet){or if there are n number of sources i need the one record only}not with the 'email'(as email will be choosen when only one record is present with the unique key and source is email)
query using:

```
db.customer.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "active": true,
            "dealerCode": { "$in": ["111391"] },
            "source": { "$in": ["email", "TV", "internet"] }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": {
                "firstName": "$personalInfo.firstName",
                "lastName": "$personalInfo.lastName",
                "code": "$vehicle.code"
            },
            "source": {
                $addToSet: { "source": "$source" }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $redact:
        {
            $cond: [
                { $eq: [{ $ifNull: ["$source", "other"] }, "email"] },
                "$$PRUNE",
                "$$DESCEND"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            "source":
            {
                $map:
                {
                    "input": {
                        $cond: [
                            { $eq: [{ $size: "$source" }, 0] },
                            [{ "source": "email" }],
                            "$source"
                        ]
                    },
                    "as": "inp",
                    "in": "$$inp.source"
                }
            },
            "record": { "_id": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

sample output:

```
{ "_id" : { "firstName" : "sGI6YaJ36WRfI4xuJQzI7A==", "lastName" : "99eQ7i+uTOqO8X+IPW+NOA==", "code" : "1GTHK23688F113955" }, "source" : ["internet"] }
{ "_id" : { "firstName" : "WYDROTF/9vs9O7XhdIKd5Q==", "lastName" : "BM18Uq/ltcbdx0UJOXh7Sw==", "code" : "1G4GE5GV5AF180133" }, "source" : ["internet"] }
{ "_id" : { "firstName" : "id+U2gYNHQaNQRWXpe34MA==", "lastName" : "AIs1G33QnH9RB0nupJEvjw==", "code" : "1G4GE5EV0AF177966" }, "source" : ["internet"] }
{ "_id" : { "firstName" : "qhreJVuUA5l8lnBPVhMAdw==", "lastName" : "petb0Qx3YPfebSioY0wL9w==", "code" : "1G1AL55F277253143" }, "source" : ["TV"] }
{ "_id" : { "firstName" : "qhreJVuUA5l8lnBPVhMAdw==", "lastName" : "6LB/NmhbfqTagbOnHFGoog==", "code" : "1GCVKREC0EZ168134" }, "source" : ["TV", "internet"] }
```

This is a problem with this query please suggest :(

Comment: Apologies for the comments here originally, someone got rather stressed! I don't know Mongo, but hopefully someone will be able to answer this. I _think_ there is enough information here to answer this.

Answer (score 4):

Your code doesn't work, because [***$cond***](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) is not an accumulator operator. Only [these](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator) accumulator operators, can be used in a `$group` stage.

Assuming your records contain not more than two possible values of `source` as you mention in your question, you could add a conditional `$project` stage and modify the `$group` stage as,

**Code:**

```js
    db.customer.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": {
                    "id": "$id",
                    "firstName": "$firstName",
                    "lastName": "$lastName",
                    "code": "$code"
                },
                "sourceA": { $first: "$source" },
                "sourceB": { $last: "$source" }
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "source": {
                    $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$sourceA", "email"] },
                        "$sourceB",
                        "$sourceA"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

In case there can be more that two possible values for source, then you could do the following:

- `Group` by the `id`, `firstName`, `lastName` and `code`. Accumulate
  the unique values of `source`, using the [***$addToSet***](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator.
- Use [***$redact***](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to keep only the values other than `email`.
- `Project` the required fields, if the `source` array is empty(all the elements have been removed), add a 
  value `email` to it.
- `Unwind` the source field to list it as a field and not an array.
  (optional)

**Code:**

```js
    db.customer.aggregate([
        {
            $group: {
                "_id": {
                    "id": "$id",
                    "firstName": "$firstName",
                    "lastName": "$lastName",
                    "code": "$code"
                },
                "sourceArr": { $addToSet: { "source": "$source" } }
            }
        },
        {
            $redact: {
                $cond: [
                    { $eq: [{ $ifNull: ["$source", "other"] }, "email"] },
                    "$$PRUNE",
                    "$$DESCEND"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                "source": {
                    $map: {
                        "input":
                        {
                            $cond: [
                                { $eq: [{ $size: "$sourceArr" }, 0] },
                                [{ "source": "item" }],
                                "$sourceArr"]
                        },
                        "as": "inp",
                        "in": "$$inp.source"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Could you please briefly explain the redact property and 

{$redact:{$cond:[{$eq:[{$ifNull:["$source","other"]},"email"]},
          "$$PRUNE",
          "$$DESCEND"]}},

Comment: @RishabhPandey - The `redact` operator takes a document at a particular level, checks if the document at that level has met a particular condition, based on the output of the condition, it can either descend into the document's sub documents or prune the document or keep the document as it is and not descend. If it chooses to descend into the sub documents, the same condition will be applied to that document and recursively traverses the sub documents unless a keep or prune can be applied or no more sub documents exist.redact works only on documents and sub documents .

Comment: @RishabhPandey You're most welcome. Yes that would be fine. That depends upon your use case. If possible you could store source as an array of values. That would better from a design perspective. Yes you could do it with a `$project`, to get the other fields. You could add a new question if you fail after trying several times. It is definitely possible.

Comment: @RishabhPandey - Can you please update your question with the records in question. Sorry couldn't make out from your comment.

Comment: @BatScream-Hello I have updated the question with the scenario where query is breaking.please see