# $project is not working in mongo query

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am writing a query to fetch unique customer record from the customer collection`customer (id,firstName,lastName,code,source,Address(city,zip,state))` based on key(firstName+lastName+code) and choose a particular source if duplicate comes. For that query is this

`db.customer.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "active" : true , "dealerCode" : { "$in" : [ "111391"]} , "source" : { "$in" : [ "email","TV"]}}},
{$group:{"_id":{"firstName":"$personalInfo.firstName","lastName":"$personalInfo.lastName","code":"$vehicle.code"},         "source":{$addToSet:{"source":"$source"},{"active":"$active"}}}},{$redact:{$cond:[{$eq:[{$ifNull:["$source","other"]},"email"]},"$$PRUNE","$$DESCEND"]}},
{$project:{"source":{$map:{"input":{$cond:[{$eq:[{$size:"$source"},0]},[{"source":"email"}],"$source"]},"as":"inp","in":"$$inp.source"}}}}])`

Moreover i want to fetch some extra fields to export field like  state,zip information. due to group condition  I am getting field that are only present in group condition.Is there any way to get these field along with this query??

Sample document:

```
{
        "_class" : "Customer",
        "_id" : ObjectId("546330b0a61818ed7ad88337"),
        "account" : {
                "accountCreationTimestamp" : ISODate("2014-11-12T10:04:32.062Z"),
                "accountModifiedTimestamp" : ISODate("2014-11-12T10:04:32.062Z"),
                "accountType" : "Unknown",                    
                "currentResidual" : 2145.34,
                "estimatedEquity" : 47896.85,
                "estimatedMarketValue" : 50000,  ,
                "originalOdometer" : 0,
                "originalSalesPerson" : {
                        "firstName" : "DATA",
                        "lastName" : "TEST7",
                        "fhash" : -2073145895,
                        "lhash" : 79713765,
                        "sortHash" : NumberLong("25714102020783")
                },
                "outstandingBalance" : 2103.15,
                "payoffQuoteRequested" : false,
                "purchaseOptionFee" : 0,
                "securityDeposit" : 0,
                "serviceAgreement" : false,
                "term" : 21,
                "totalAccounts" : 1,
                "turnInFee" : 0,
                "valuations" : [
                        {
                                "vin" : "1GTHK23688F113955",
                                "source" : "BB",
                                "value" : 50000,
                                "lastUpdated" : ISODate("2014-11-12T13:06:56.410Z")
                        }
                ],
                "warrantyTerm" : 0
        },
        "active" : true,
        "coBuyer" : {
                "firstName" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w==",
                "lastName" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w==",
                "fhash" : 985088,
                "lhash" : 985088,
                "sortHash" : NumberLong("985088985088"),
                "address" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w==",
                "city" : "",
                "state" : "",
                "zip" : "",
                "homePhone" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w==",
                "workPhone" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w==",
                "cellPhone" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w==",
                "email" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w=="
        },
        "creationTimestamp" : ISODate("2014-11-12T10:04:32.062Z"),
        "dealerCode" : "111391",
        "finRecordId" : "13",
        "maturity" : {
                "programEligibility" : false,
                "contacted" : false,
                "inspected" : false,
                "communicated" : false,
                "surveyed" : false,
                "customerContacted" : false,
                "closed" : false
        },
        "modifiedTimestamp" : ISODate("2014-11-12T15:10:43.553Z"),
        "personalInfo" : {
                "firstName" : "sGI6YaJ36WRfI4xuJQzI7A==",
                "lastName" : "99eQ7i+uTOqO8X+IPW+NOA==",
                "fhash" : 2575080,
                "lhash" : 2544060,
                "sortHash" : NumberLong("25440602575080"),
                "address" : "BAR+Hh6CWTWcgVo6rLtVaw==",
                "city" : "MENOKEN",
                "state" : "ND",
                "zip" : "58558",
                "homePhone" : "1cIO6YavoApacCMsw7kKMw==",
                "workPhone" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w==",
                "cellPhone" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w==",
                "email" : "cQjBRetBuq2m1ARv5vb13w=="
        },
        "source" : "WF",
        "valuationRequired" : true,
        "vehicle" : {
                "code" : "1GTHK23688F113955",
                "year" : "2005",
                "make" : "CHEVROLET TRUCK",
                "model" : "EQUINOX-V6",
                "Desc" : "2005 CHEVROLET TRUCK EQUINOX-V6",
                "options" : [ ],
                "invalidVin" : true
        }
}
```

I know it's a heavy :). personalInfo.firstName,personalInfo.lastName,vehichle.code.I need to fetch details from PersonalInfo,Vehicle,Account(not all fields but some particular fields)

Comment: Can you Please update your question with a sample document from your collection. Since it is not clear how the address is stored, when you say `Address(city,zip,state)`.

Comment: I have added the sample document.Please look into this :)

Comment: Your requirements are fuzzy. The current aggregation pipeline is definitely not the right path - `$redact` has no place here. Can you show us what you want the output to look like? I'm piecing together that you want one `source : email` document per `(firstName, lastName, code)`, including other fields of the document, but what if there are multiple `source : email` docs for one value of the grouping key? Will any one document do?

Comment: Good Catch. The `redact` is incomplete here.

Comment: @wdberkeley -Suppose if there are 3 documents with same group key and 3 different source(i.e. 'Email','friend','TV') then i want to choose only one other than email.either with source friend or tv.@batscream: could you please rectify if anything is missing

Comment: @wdberkeley-[Connected question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28191069/mongodb-query-with-conditional-group-by-statement/28204571?noredirect=1#comment44814168_28204571) you can see the details here

Comment: You probably cannot do this in a single aggregation pipeline.  To help you more, I would find it helpful to know if you are going to run this query just once, or if it is going to be an ongoing requirement.  If it's one-time, you should be able to use a sequence of two aggregation pipelines.  Otherwise, I will probably recommend maintaining a separate collection with data to avoid the need for aggregation.

Comment: @i80and- am implementing an ETL job and I need to export customer details for this so probably it will be used once in a month.
creating another collection is not an option for me as it's just a requirement for an ETL job.

Comment: @i80and-how can i use sequence of two aggregation pipelines?Could you please explain?I just need to get extra fields  required but this time if am adding any field it is breaking my unique records

Comment: @BatScream-I have updated the query.Could you please suggest how to get any field for the document.If I can get _id only then it would be also manageable.As I am building my query on yours base query